# Разбить строку на подстроки регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Предположим есть некая строка однородных символов, например, `aaaaa`. Возможно ли регуляркой разбить эту строку на подстроки `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, `aaaa`, `aaaaa`, т.е. таким образом, чтобы у нас получилось что-то вроде счёта от одного до количества символов в строке? Вопрос для раcширения кругозора.

Comment: Одно регулярное выражение не будет сопоставлять первую букву `a` пяти разным подстрокам. Одна буква -> не более  одного сопоставления.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, есть решения покрасивее, но вот первое, что пришло в голову :) (python)

```py
import re

string = 'aaaaa'
for n in range(1, len(string), 1):
    print(re.search(r'.{' + str(n) + r'}', string).group(0))
```

UPD: ты пробудил во мне спортивный интерес. Держи :)

```py
re.findall(r'(?P<q>.(?P<w>.(?P<e>.(?P<r>.))))', string))
```

Comment: Через цикл то я и сам могу. Речь была именно про регулярку.

Comment: @Марат на сколько я знаю, в регулярных выражениях нет возможности использования циклов, а тут без него ну никак не получится.

Comment: Есть ведь группы! Каким образом составить регулярку, чтобы она разбила строку на указанные ранее мной подгруппы?

Comment: @Марат но группы все равно идут по-порядку, то есть, например (?P<q>.).+ выведет нам 1 ‘а’,  (?P<q>.) (?P<w>.{2}).+ выведет нам 1ю ‘а’ как 1 группу, и 2, 3 ‘а’ как вторую группу, но смысл в том, что вторая группа физически не может захватить первую ‘а’. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил:)

Comment: @Марат используя цикл и переменные, можно обойтись 1 группой и регуляркой ‘.{х}’